# Is it possible to load custom fonts for a custom panel only?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel, font

I would like to load a custom font specifically for one custom panel. This maybe impossible but I just want to know.

[image: Quick image I made as a example]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to select individual fonts in that way.  UILayout is pretty much completely lacking in font control.

Comment: Thats what i figured kinda

Comment: @MartyFouts please add this as an answer

Comment: @TheLabCat done.  hopefully it won't get flagged as too short ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to select individual fonts in that way. [UILayout](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) is pretty much completely lacking in font control.